# div's with each 6 results in it PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, equals

```
<div>
<?php   if ($result->num_rows > 0) { 
$i=1;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 

        if( $i % 6 == 0 )
        { ?>        
            </div>
            <div>
    <?php } ?>
    <h4><?php echo $row["city"] ?></h4>
    <h6><?php echo $row["info"] ?></h6>
<?php   $i++;
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
?>
</div>
```

Goal: div's with each `6` rows in it.
When I use `$i=1`, the first gets `5` results and the other ones get `6`.
When I use `$i=0` the first one is empty and the other ones get `6`.

How to get the first div also filled with `6` results?

Comment: It's already in the post: When I use $i=0 the first one (div) is empty and the other  get 6

Comment: something like `for ($i = 1, $j = 1; $i <= $resut->num_rows; $i++) { echo "<div>"; if ($i <= 6 * $j) { echo $row[$i - 1]; } if ($i % 6 == 0) { echo "</div>"; $j++; } }`?

Comment: Accepted answer is actually wrong as it is an overhead and just wrong code understanding. The real issue with your code (which is generally fine) only in location of printing enclosing `div` tag which must be _after_ printing data.

Comment: Owww, can you show it to me please? The other solution is working, so I don't really understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `array_chunk` as proposed by @Justinas is a good way to refactor code. Yet, taking your original code, the issue is about where you check printed amount. It is wrong to first check output amount as it breaks the logic for the first iteration. Please, refer to the code below.

```
<div>
<?php

if ($result->num_rows > 0) { 
    $i = 1;
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        # if ($i % 6 == 0) {     
        #     echo '</div><div>';
        # }
        # move commented code from above to ...

        echo "<h4>{$row["city"]}</h4>";
        echo "<h6>{$row["info"]}</h6>";

        # ... here
        if ($i % 6 == 0) {     
            echo '</div><div>';
        }

        $i++;
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: That's also working. Now I don't know what's better. This way, or Justinas way.

Comment: @user2375199 "my way" fixed your code issue. Justinas way is a better way to refactor it.

Comment: Hmm don't know what to do. I tried his code, but I get an parse error. I'm not that good in this, so I guess I oversee the problem. :-S

Answer (score 4):

Try using [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php). That way you don't have to worry where to put your div ends and it's more readable:

```
$rows = [];
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}

foreach (array_chunk($rows, 6) as $subset) {
    echo "<div>";
    foreach ($subset as $row) {
        echo "<h4>{$row["city"]}</h4>"
        echo "<h6>{$row["info"]}</h6>"
    }
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Comment: Trying to make this work. I get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' on the foreach (array_chunk($rows, 6), $subnet)

Comment: @user2375199 Well, try debugging first. I obviously left a typo in first loop

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting `$i = 0` then excluding it in your `if` statement with

```
if ($i > 0 && $i % 6 == 0)
```

since 0 % 6 == 0.

Comment: Not enough reputation for comment :'(

Comment: @JustCarty why a comment. If it worked it would be a valid answer.

Comment: It is wrong. Please, see my comment under question.